# Active passive problem

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

(**Active voice**):

> He has written a poem which fascinates everyone

My problem here is , in active voice the **object** is **the poem** then passive voice should be :

> **A poem has been written by him which fascinates everyone.**

but the answer is

(**Passive voice**):

> Everyone is fascinated by the poem which has been written by him.

Comment: It should be "a poem which fascinates everyone has been written by him".

Comment: @user178049: please make it a proper answer, so we can up-vote it.